# How can I create a Modal BottomSheet with blur background instead of the default gray translucent one

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, bottom-sheet

I am using a Modal Bottom Sheet, how can I change the default grey translucent background with a blurred one, like we see in iOS

Comment: In BottomSheet, definitely we have to use layout with views like recyclerview etc. We can set background color to parent layout.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry) library. It has options to customize blurry effect like color, radius, sampling etc. 
Add this to your app level gradle `compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'`

The implementation is also very simple Refer this code.

```
Blurry.with(context)

 //style the blur with your color and effects with radius and sampling
 .radius(10)
 .sampling(8) 
 .color(Color.argb(66, 255, 255, 0))

 .animate(500) //optional
 //always use ViewGroup instance, avoid casting other view to viewgroup, it wont work
 .onto(rootView); //Use your bottom sheet layout's rootview here.
```